# Redirect Tomcat/Jenkins URL to root

Tags: tomcat, nginx, jenkins, proxy, url-rewriting

I have tomcat running on port 8080 and Jenkins was deployed and run on top of Tomcat. So my Jenkins URL is: http://myserver.com:8080/jenkins

I'm looking for a way to config my Nginx that when I request http://myserver.com, it will response content of http://myserver.com:8080/jenkins but without changing the URL. So in short:

http://myserver.com === http://myserver.com:8080/jenkins

My current Nginx config is but not quite what I want yet:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location /jenkins {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/;
        }

        location / {
            rewrite ^/$ /jenkins last;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you found any solution for this. Currently i am also facing same issue.

Comment: @RohitMaurya no I have not